# Applescript application read from file

Tags: file-io, applescript

I have a compiled AppleScript application which I have moved to my windows server. I'd like to then insert a text file into the application (which looks like a zip file on windows):

```
myapplescript.app/Contents/Resources/MyNewDir/MyTxtFile.txt
```

So, I've precompiled the AppleScript to try to read from this text file and get the contents as a string. This is what I do:

```
set theFolder to POSIX path of (the path to me)
set theFile to theFolder & "Contents/Resources/MyNewDir/MyTxtFile.txt"
open for access theFile
set fileContents to (read theFile)
close access theFile
```

but this is the error I get:

> Can't make
>   "/Users/mike/Desktop/myapplescript.app/Contents/Resources/MyNewDir/MyTxtFile.txt"
>   into type file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, I changed the second line to this:

```
set theFile to (POSIX file (theFolder & "Contents/Resources/MyNewDir/MyTxtFile.txt"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a single line version of read:

```
read POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt" as «class utf8»
```

Both versions use MacRoman unless you add `as «class utf8»`. (`as Unicode text` is UTF-16.)

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file via a file path in a variable.

The 1st two work.  The 3rd, which stores the file name in variable does not.

set myData to read file POSIX file ¬
    "/Users/sww/Devel/afile.csv"

set myData to read file ¬
        "Macintosh HD:Users:sww:Devel:afile.csv"

```
set fRef to "Macintosh HD:Users:sww:Devel:afile.csv"

set myData to read file fRef  -- No good
```

To fix?  Give the file reference as a string.

```
set myData to read file (fRef as string)  -- OK
```